# POST http://localhost:3000/users/register 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have created a react client and sending my register form request to node server but I am getting the following error in my console while clicking the register button.

"POST http://localhost:3000/users/register 404 (Not Found)"

Please suggest a solution to it?

**../routes/User.js**

```
const users = express.Router()
const cors = require('cors')
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

const User = require("../models/User")
users.use(cors())

process.env.SECRET_KEY = 'secret'

users.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const today = new Date()
    const userData = {
        first_name: req.body.first_name,
        last_name: req.body.last_name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        created: today
    }
    User.findOne({
        where: {
            email: req.body.email
         }
    })
        .then(user => {
            if(!user){
                bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
                    userData.password = hash
                    User.create(userData)
                        .then(user => {
                            res.json({status: user.email + ' registered'})
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            res.send('error: ' + err)
                        })
                })  
            }   else {
                res.json({error: "User already exists"})
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.send('error: ' + err)
        })
})

users.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({
        where: {
            email: req.body.email
        }
    })
    .then(user => {
        if(user) {
            if(bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) {
                let token = jwt.sign(user.dataValues, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
                    expiresin: 1440
                })
                res.send(token)
            }
        } else {
            res.status(400).json({error: 'User does not exist'})
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).json({ error: err})
    })
})

module.exports = users
```

**../client/App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import Landing from './components/Landing'
import Login from './components/Login'
import Register from './components/Register'
import Profile from './components/Profile'

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
        <div className="container">
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**../client/src/Register.js**

```
import { register } from './UserFunctions'

class Register extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            first_name: '',
            last_name: '',
            email: '',
            password: ''
        }

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
    }

    onChange(e){
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: [e.target.value]})
    }

    onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault()

        const user = {
            first_name: this.state.first_name,
            last_name: this.state.last_name,
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        }
        register(user).then(res=> {
                this.props.history.push(`/login`)
        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6 mt-5 mx-auto">
                        <form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                            <h1 className="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="first_name">First Name</label>
                                <input type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                name="first_name"
                                placeholder="Enter First Name"
                                value={this.state.first_name}
                                onChange={this.onChange}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="last_name">Last Name</label>
                                <input type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                name="last_name"
                                placeholder="Enter Last Name"
                                value={this.state.last_name}
                                onChange={this.onChange}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="email">Email Address</label>
                                <input type="email"
                                className="form-control"
                                name="email"
                                placeholder="Enter Email"
                                value={this.state.email}
                                onChange={this.onChange}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                                <input type="password"
                                className="form-control"
                                name="password"
                                placeholder="Enter Password"
                                value={this.state.password}
                                onChange={this.onChange}/>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit"
                            className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
                                Register
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Register
```

**../server.js**

```
var cors = require ('cors')
var bodyParser = require("body-parser")
var app = express()
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))

var Users = require('./routes/users')

app.use('/users', Users)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server is running at port: " + port)
})
```

**./client/src/UserFunctions.js**

```
export const register = newUser => {
    return axios
    .post('users/register', {
        first_name: newUser.firstname,
        last_name: newUser.last_name,
        email: newUser.email,
        password: newUser.password
    })
    .then(res => {
        console.log("Registered");
    })
}

export const login = user => {
    return axios
    .post('users/login', {
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password
    })
    .then(res=>{
        localStorage.setItem('usertoken', res.data)
        return res.data
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

Comment: I can't see from where `/users/` part is coming into the URL.can you show that code?

Comment: I have some other code that I haven't shared. let me share that too.

Comment: `var Users = require('./routes/users')` while file name is .`./routes/User.js`. Is this intentional?

Comment: I have followed the tutorial to do so. Shall I change it to ./routes/User.js?

Comment: Change filename to Users.js, follow this [link](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router)

Comment: I did. Now I am getting --> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Did you try to debug, try to identify the issue, 1) Are you able to get inside the route 2) Code inside post is throwing this error and then proceed from there.

Comment: Can you share a snippet of your `register` function from `UserFunctions`?

Comment: Just do `app.use(Users);` since you are using `Router` to handle routes.

Comment: @LadiAden I have updated my post, now you can see my UserFunctions.js for register function. Please help

Comment: @Prasad I tried your solution. but still the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this, it seems the problem may be with your client code.

You're trying to access `http://localhost:3000/users/register`, which is an inexistent route on your client but it exists on the server as `http://localhost:5000/users/register`. (that's assuming that your server is running on port `5000`).

If your server is running on port `5000`, you can try this in your register function...

```
return axios.post('http://localhost:5000/users/register') // add the rest of your code
```

Unless you have a proxy for your server set up in the client, you'll keep getting that error.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193578/discussion-on-answer-by-ladi-aden-post-http-localhost3000-users-register-404).